# How can I use a SideWinder 3D Pro with a modern PC running Windows 7?

Tags: old-hardware-adaptation, joystick

I've got a sweet joystick that uses gameport, and I'd like to use it in my Kerbal Space Program. My modern PC lacks any ISA or PCI slots, so I can't use the cards I have.

I've noticed some gameport to USB adapters on the net - but they are somewhat expensive, and I wonder how well they perform; I've been burned by Parallel to USB adapters in the past already, so I'm wary of purchasing this kind of hardware without doing my research first. Or maybe there are other, better options? Like a PCIE card with gameport?

What are my options, and your recommendations?

The PC is running Windows 7, the joystick is [Microsoft Sidewinder 3D Pro.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SideWinder#3D_Pro)

Comment: And I'm surprised by the price of USB adapters nowadays! I paid around $10 for the ones I've got, many years ago (but they weren't scarce then).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The SideWinder 3D Pro has its own protocol, which isn't supported by typical gameport-to-USB adapters. The best you can hope for with one of those is to find an adapter which supports the CH Flightstick Pro or Thrustmaster FCS protocols, and use the fallback mode on the SideWinder. (There's usually a switch on the USB adapter to choose the appropriate mode.) Earlier SideWinders came with a USB adapter (part 98427) but that doesn't work with the 3D Pro.

The protocol has been reverse engineered though and it is possible to *build* an adapter. The basic recipe is described [on the Descent forums](http://descentbb.net/viewtopic.php?t=15526) (another version of the post, with photos, is available [on the Mechwarrior Online forums](http://mwomercs.com/forums/topic/4767-ms-sidewinder-3d-pro-usb-conversion/)). The build documented there uses a Teensy board; it's also possible to use an Arduino board instead.

Answer (score 5):

SOLVED!!!

After hours and hours of reading forums, installing different drivers and emulators, I managed to get it running on Windows7 64Bits and try it in PlanetSide2... Finally I can fly aircraft!!! :D

The solution is to install WinWiner and vJoy. I leave you with an explanatory video. A link to the download is in the description. Greetings

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJ3-L5P7c-g